# Can 'Snow in a can' be checked in luggage for a flight?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, australia, delta-air-lines, snow

Bizarre question I know, but I'm traveling to Australia from Canada and want to bring snow in a can for the tree as you can't buy any there. The product is non flammable however is an aerosol can. I hear all international (large) planes are pressurized so it should be fine.. Has anyone else flown with fake snow before? I would have it in checked luggage obviously as I wouldn't need it for the flight ahhaa.

Comment: Before I clicked, I thought this was going to be about a can full of water :)

Comment: I did a search for "snow in a can spray australia" and got several hits on .au shopping sites that offer it.

Comment: @stevie what airline are you using?

Comment: There's a different "snow in a can" product which isn't aerosol, but you add water to it and it fluffs up. You should be able to take as much of this as you can fit in your luggage. But I don't think that would work as well for applying to a tree...

Comment: As long as it is in the can, isn't it technically not an aerosol?

Comment: @Dorothy: pnuts added it to a deleted answer several hours earlier, it appears.  I think they should undelete their answer now.

Comment: @Dorothy: pnuts wrote an answer that said "no", then deleted it, then edited it to say "yes" with this link.  It's visible below to 10K users.  I can't ping them because they haven't commented here, and I can't comment on a deleted post.

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek ice is technically not a liquid, but try that with airport security

Answer (score 5):

The Canadian Air Transport Security Authority has a [master list](http://www.catsa.gc.ca/complete-item-list) of allowed and prohibited items.  Under "Aerosol spray bottles/cans" it says aerosols are allowed in checked luggage, but limited to 500ml per can and 2 liters total.

So if your can is less than 500 ml, and you have less than 2 liters of aerosols total, then you can put it in your checked luggage.

(Credit: pnuts already mentioned this link, but their answer is deleted.)